# Child process is able to change parent epoll state

Tags: c++, linux, epoll

I am trying to figure out why a child process is able to change a parent epoll state.

I have program that declare a static epoll object (an object that wraps epoll):

`static EventManager* evMgrPtr = NULL;`

The parent process initialized it and use it to watch a listening socket (The parent is basically a daemon that occasionally need to respond to health check request by accepting these request through the listening socket).

The children does totally different thing, however, the program DOES NOT do a fork/exec, rather, the children carry on and run a piece of code in the same translation unit.

```
      pid_t pid = fork();
      switch(pid) {
      case -1:
        YREPL_LOG_FATAL("Couldn't start server process ");
        exit(EXIT_OK);

      case 0:
    #ifndef __FreeBSD__ 
        assert( closeThisFd != -1 );
        evMgr.unregisterSocketEvent( closeThisFd );
        close( closeThisFd );
    #endif
        close(outpipe[0]);
        close(errpipe[0]);
        dup2(outpipe[1], 1);
        dup2(errpipe[1], 2);
        close(outpipe[1]);
        close(errpipe[1]);
```

The problem is that after I do evMgrPtr->unregisterSocketEvent( closeThisFd ) in the child process, I found out the parent stop watching for the listening socket as well!!!

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening. I thought once a fork is executed the parent and children will do COW. So whatever children does to its copy of the epoll object should not get reflected in the parent right?

Comment: File descriptors are unique in the overall inherited process space. If you want do have independent handling from the child process, refer to [`dup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) please.

Comment: I don't think I want to dup() the inherited fd. All I want to do is have the parent keep listening on the port while stopping any subsequent forked children from listening on the port as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use EPOLL-based event loop. So, since file descriptor for epoll-object itself is shared between child and parent, removing file descriptor from epoll()-based descriptor in child also affects parent process :). Please read man epoll, man epoll_create.

Comment: As you can see from the code fragment that the code was ported from FreeBSD to RHEL. In the FreeBSD implementation, it uses kqueue which apparently will not shared the queue across fork as the man page suggested. Is there a similar event mechanism exist for RHEL? Which a event queue do not get shared between the parent/children?

Comment: According to the epoll man page. "Whenever  a descriptor  is  duplicated  via  dup(2),  dup2(2),  fcntl(2)  F_DUPFD, or fork(2), a new file descriptor referring to the same open file description is created.  An open file description continues to exist until all file descriptors referring to it  have  been  closed. A file  descriptor is removed from an epoll set only after all the file descriptors referring to the underlying open file description have been closed (or before if the descriptor is explicitly removed using epoll_ctl() EPOLL_CTL_DEL)."